# HttpServletRequest to HttpRequest conversion

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Is there any third-party library for converting an HttpServletRequest to HttpRequest (org.apache.http.HttpRequest) ? Offcourse we can write our own implementation by copying the headers, body, etc to the HttpRequest. But is there any third party library which already does that?

Comment: A `HttpServletRequest` is essentially a `HttpRequest` with additional information. Why do you need to do this conversion?

Comment: In some of the API gateway servers, they used to make an HTTP request with the properties of the request they receive (if the gateway server uses java they are doing this conversion internally I guess). And also httpservletrequest and HttpRequest are two different implementations. I just have to write a parser for the conversion. But I just want to know whether is there any third party library for this.